# Horizontal lookup using unstructured lookup keys

Tags: google-sheets

I need to find the rate for a given location and weight, using a lookup table that lists rates per location and weight. The problem is that the weights in the table are formatted like `Up to 2 kg`, `2.01-3 kg`, `3.01-5 kg` and so on, while the weights I am looking for are plain numbers like `10.5` and `13.5`. How can I map the location-weight tuples to the rates in the lookup table?

[Spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c7_CAeNujXNtgtibtXF40M0YxCeSyXVkqcyGOPM1gSE/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to obtain something like this:

[image]

where you input a location in the `A9` cell and a Weight in the `B9` cell and it automatically puts the correct rate in the `C9` cell. This can be achieved with the following formula (in the `C9` cell):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A9,A1:G5,HLOOKUP(B9,{A1:G1;COLUMN(A1:G1)},2,0),0))
```

which mixes **VLOOKUP** (you can read more about it [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)) to fetch the correct Location Code with **HLOOKUP** (you can read more about it [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375?hl=en)) to fetch the correct Weight.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very simply by just nesting one FILTER inside another; as per the answer given by Oriel Castander you could use this formula in cell C9 instead:

```
=filter(filter(B2:G5,A2:A5=A9),B1:G1=B9)
```